# mysql: How to get the last value of a column, and the first value of another coumn in the same table?

Tags: mysql

how can I only retrieve the following data from the table below with one query

1. MIN(SamplingStart) -
2. First StartAddress // [WHERE StartAddress = MIN(SamplingStart)] -
3. Last StartAddress   // [WHERE StartAddress = MAX(SamplingStart)]

This is the code I have so far. The problem is with number 3 above. How can I get no 3 to work while 1,2 must still work.

```
**The result must look like this.**

+-----------+--------------------+----------------+
| StartTime | StartAddress       | StopAddress    |
+-----------+--------------------+----------------+
| 08:00:00  | 26 Riverside Drive | Paterson       |
+-----------+--------------------+----------------

**Existing Code to modify.**

SELECT 

MIN(SamplingStart) AS StartTime,
StartAddress AS StartAddress, 
StopAddress AS StopAddress

FROM table1;


****table1****
+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| SamplingStart | StartAddress       | StopAddress        |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 08:00:00      | 26 Riverside Drive | 70 Piet Retief     |
| 09:00:00      | 10 Glen Drive      | 16 Olga Street     |
| 10:00:00      | 66 Bremerhof       | 26 Bluewater Drive |
| 11:00:00      | 7 New Street       | Walker Drive       |
| 13:00:00      | Goodwood Street    | Blouberg           |
| 15:00:00      | Marine Drive       | William Moffet     |
| 18:00:00      | Jumanji            | Paterson           |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------------
```

Comment: I would go for subquery for stopadress. But you asked for one query?

Comment: Ok. I'm very new to mysql. I googled subquery, and to me it looks like it might work. I'm going to play around with it and let you know if I need more help:-) Thanks!!

Comment: No problem. You are very welcome. See my answer below for an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this(I know it is not really just one query but...):

```
SELECT 
MIN(SamplingStart) AS StartTime,
StartAddress AS StartAddress, 
(select StopAddress from table1 order by SamplingStart desc limit 0,1) as StopAddress

FROM table1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(SamplingStart) AS StartTime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SamplingStart = StartTime THEN StartAddress END) AS StartAddress, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN SamplingStart = EndTime THEN StopAddress END) AS StopAddress
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(SamplingStart) AS StartTime, MAX(SamplingStart) AS ENDTime
      FROM table1
     ) tt
```